# Allow CORS from one Next.js app to another

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cors, vercel

so I've written an API inside a Next.js app because it'll allow me to host for free and do some other things which are just easier to do through Next (for me, because I'm used to how it works). But I'm getting CORS errors when sending requests from my other Next.js app. I've read a few docs on how to allow CORS but it's not working. Can anyone help with this?

*api route file* `api/routes/data`

```
const data = require('../data/data.json');

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // Run cors
    await res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    await res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );

    await res.status(200).json(data);
}
```

*next config file* `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        // matching all API routes
        source: "/api/routes/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*error*

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.covidstatistics.co/api/routes/data' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
hidden.js?65f8:47 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?770c:16:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?1a5c:117:1)
```

*function to request data* (this code is in the other Next.js app)

```
const getData = async () => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.covidstatistics.co/api/routes/data',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        }

    }
    axios.request(options)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Just to clarify the API I'm trying to call is on a different Next.js app than where I'm making the requests from: https://covidstatistics.co and https://api.covidstatistics.co

*EDIT*

Headers from network tab in Chrome dev tools,

```
General
  Request URL: http://localhost:3001/api/routes/data
  Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers
  Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Referer: http://localhost:3000/
```

*I changed the API calls to call localhost so I don't need to push to production every time I make a change*

**UPDATE, SOLVED**
So the file structure will look like this

```
/.next
/lib
  init-middleware.js
/node_modules
/pages
  /api
    cors.js
/public
/styles
```

*./lib/init-middleware.js*
Run `npm install cors --save`

```
// Helper method to wait for a middleware to execute before continuing
// And to throw an error when an error happens in a middleware
export default function initMiddleware(middleware) {
    return (req, res) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        middleware(req, res, (result) => {
          if (result instanceof Error) {
            return reject(result)
          }
          return resolve(result)
        })
      })
}
```

*./pages/api/cors.js*

```
import Cors from 'cors'
import initMiddleware from '../../lib/init-middleware'

// Initialize the cors middleware
const cors = initMiddleware(
  // You can read more about the available options here: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options
  Cors({
    // Only allow requests with GET, POST and OPTIONS
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
  })
)

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Run cors
  await cors(req, res)

  // Rest of the API logic
  res.json({ message: "NEW MESSAGE" })
}
```

I found this code online late last night and forgot where I found it so note *I did not write this code*

Comment: Your origin is in `http`. Make sure you're using `https` on all api's. If you intend on calling a live api over the internet.